# Algorithm time complexity question: which Q&A shall I post it to?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question that is about the time complexity of a textbook algorithm. Which Q&A shall I post my question to?

Stack Overflow is about programming, so would that fit?
CS Theory is about research-level questions, so would that fit?

Comment: can you show us the actual question you want to ask? it's hard to guess which Q&A site your question goes to without seeing the actual question :)

Comment: What really bakes my cookie: To which meta should this question be asked???

Comment: @ChrisWesseling The Meta Stack Exchange would globally work. But given the direct question about SO and the audience that visits here, it works on MSO as well. P.s. can I have that cookie?

Comment: +1 kudo's for not just posting any brainfart on SO to just get a big audience.

Comment: see: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `time-complexity` tag on [TCS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-complexity), [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-complexity) *and* [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-complexity).

Post it on SO if your question is about implementing it in some language or the consequences of differences in runtimes for a different language; as the time-complexity doesn't say all about performance of an algorithm.

The difference between cs and cstheory can be found on the [TCS about page](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/about)

> We welcome you to join us in asking and answering research-level questions in theoretical computer science.
>
> For undergraduate-level questions please visit Computer Science which has a broader scope.

Since your question is about a *textbook* algorithm and not a *research paper* one, I'd guess CS is the place to post. Whatever you do *don't crosspost to both*; moderators have tools to migrate off-topic questions to the right SE site.

Comment: TCS is *only* for research level questions. That is, if you have or are working towards a PhD in the CS field then TCS is the place to go. For all others CS is usually where you should post your question (I've been corrected before for posting in TCS). So questions about time complexity of a textbook algorithm definitely should be in CS (although you'll probably get an answer faster on SO).